# Internal Server Error #500 while trying to display JSONResult with jQuery ajax and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-ajax

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult TeamInfo(string teamName)
            {
                teamDA = new TeamDataAccess();
                var teamInfo = teamDA.TeamInfo(teamName);
               System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
             new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(teamInfo);
                JsonResult jsonResult 
=new JsonResult(){ JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }; 
                    jsonResult.Data = sJSON; // first i give this.
         jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                    return jsonResult;
                }
```

Calling Controller from jQuery

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'Team/TeamInfo/' + teamName,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#teamDetails').html(data);
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
                }
            });
```

While debugging I can see it is executing till the last line in controller `return jsonResult;` But `alert('Load was performed.');` is not visible. 
Do you know what is the reason it is not going into success part. There is no error in server side. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
When I added the `error` in ajax call. it says error 500 (internal server error). How do I find this issue ?

Comment: Why do you send back `JsonResult` if you directly put the result in the page's DOM as HTML? Try commenting out the line `$('#teamDetails').html(data);`.... to see what's happens.

Comment: Nothing. it just complete the function in controller and it is not entering the success. Is there any need to add in my code ?

Comment: Call your action from browser instead of calling by ajax. The server will return the error page for you. Or run in debug mode.

Comment: Yes I got the issue. `This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request`. Please see my updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make all the serialization stuff with JavaScriptSerializer.

Your action method could look like this:

```
 public JsonResult TeamInfo(string teamName)
 {
      return Json(new TeamDataAccess()TeamInfo(teamName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
 }
```

Comment: its works . thanks a lot. But why it is not working in my code?

Comment: i tried the above also but it won't works. can u pls tell what's d difference ?

Comment: It returns the same error on "sensitive information..." or another?

Answer (score 1):

The default request type for the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is `GET` but by default GET requests are not allowed on `JsonResult` so you need to excplicitly allow them, with the [JsonRequestBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.jsonrequestbehavior.aspx)  property:

```
JsonResult jsonResult = 
    new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
jsonResult.Data = sJSON;

return jsonResult;
```

Or you can POST with your ajax call using `type: 'POST'`

Note: It's still not clear what is your goal with putting the returned JSON directly into the DOM with the line `$('#teamDetails').html(data);`

Comment: I tried that one. But still it's not. Let me check once again. Before putting it into div I need to create some HTML.

Comment: this not works :(. But the down one works . but do not why it doesn't works ?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee `This request has been blocked...` this is the error message what you get when you don't set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. So it seams your problem was this for the whole time, maybe the app was not rebuilt or the browser cached the result... Using `return Json(...` will do basically the same what you did with creating `JsonResult` and doing the serialization manually...