# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'domain_name' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the popup as `Undefined` and showing the error as below:

> Unable to get property 'domain_name' of undefined or null reference.

Can Any body help on this

From View:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "", 
     new { id = item.id },
     new { onclick = "someFunction(" + item.id + ")", 
     href = "javascript:void(0)" })
```

Javascript

```
function someFunction(id) {

   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/")Contracts/Test/',
    data: { 'id': id },       
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.domain_name);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, exception) {
            alert("Error: " + exception + ", Status: " + status);
        }
});    
}
```

Controller action

```
enter code here
public JsonResult Test(int id)
    {
        var result = (from cntrct in db.contracts where cntrct.id == id 
              select new { cntrct.domain_name, cntrct.id}).ToArray();    
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Below is the data which I"m getting from db but can't pass to JavaScript back.
[image]

Error
[image]

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3. 
Contracts

Comment: So the error is because the data being passed back from the Json ActionResult is null; can you verify that the id is correctly being passed to `someFunction`, and that a contract with corresponding id value exists in the db?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. With that id value is existing in DB but not able to pass that data back to javascript..

Comment: HTML's ID shouldn't be only numeric.

Comment: The returned data is an array. the alert should be like, `if(data.length){ alert(data[0].domain_name); }`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oohoo!! Finally I got this... Only thing we need to do is alert(data[0].domain_name); :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in the Json Action method

**Action**

```
public JsonResult Test(int id)
{
    var result = (from cntrct in db.Contracts where cntrct.ID == id 
          select new { cntrct.domain_name, cntrct.id, cntrct......}).ToArray();    
    return Json(result);
}
```

**Script**

```
function someFunction(id) {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/")Contracts/Test/',
        data: { 'id': id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
               alert(data.domain_name);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: domain_name is there in Json data.. I can see it while debugging

Comment: I can pass the single property in this but unable to pass object to javascript from Controller...

Comment: If it's still showing the error, can you post the response Json result?

Comment: This one also not working..I'm getting error like.. GET http://localhost:54272/Contracts/Test?id=3 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
v.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
v.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
someFunction JScript1.js:21
onclick Contracts:210

Comment: Sorry, Still its not working..I have updated my question @Praveen James

Comment: Can you alert 'data' itself like this alert(data). Just to make sure the 'data' is not null. And also try this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434326/internal-server-error-500-while-trying-to-display-jsonresult-with-jquery-ajax-a

Comment: OOhoo Finally I got this... Only thing we need to do is alert(data[0].domain_name); :) Thanks for all your time... @Praveen James